# Kinect Hand tracking in xna

Tags: xna, c#, kinect

I'm trying to create an application using the Kinect to simulate the following project:

[Kinect Hand Tracking](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNzX_0cSaS8&feature=player_embedded)

I want my project to have similar usability with the Kinect tracking hand and finger positions for use in a menu system, or to navigate another system.

What I would like to know is; is it possible for the exact same to be accomplished in XNA using Kinect?

I know that it can be done in Winform / C#, but I know XNA / C# a lot better and would (ideally) prefer to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XNA doesn't natively support Kinect, so you've got to use the Kinect SDK and XNA in conjunction with each other.

However, you can use the two together fairly easily.  There's a pretty good blog [over here](http://kinectxna.blogspot.com/) that will get you from installing the SDKs all the way up to Skeletal Tracking.

The blog posts are a bit old, but all the information contained in them are still relevant.

Do note, that this is only for PC development.  Kinect support is not included for XNA on the Xbox 360.